# Why malloc consume that much memory?

Tags: c, malloc

I have project where I do lots of malloc's. I found that memory usage is much greater than the data itself. If I use valgrind and put 100 MB data allocated memory is 500 MB. The data chunks are different sizes, 20-40 bytes each. Here are minimal program that do similar thing, but with chunks of same size.

It allocates around 43 MB, but valgrind massif show 53 MB.

If run with jemalloc, top show 47 MB as well.

For the moment all chunks are different sizes and I cannot use array or something.

Is there some settings for malloc I can use or if there are different malloc-like commands I can use to minimize the wasted memory?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 39
#define MANY        1000000LU

typedef struct _list{
    void    *next;
    char    payload[BUFFER_SIZE];
}list;


int main(){
    list root;

    printf("Allocating %lu chunks %zu bytes each, equals to %lu bytes\n", MANY, sizeof(list), MANY * sizeof(list));

    list *node = & root;
    unsigned long int i;
    for(i = 0; i < MANY; i++){
        node->next = malloc(sizeof(list));

        if (node->next == NULL){
            printf("Out of memory\n");
            return 1;
        }

        memset(node->payload, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

        node = node->next;
    }

    printf("done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: malloc requests memory from the OS. The OS maps whole [page(s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)) at once to the virtual space of the process. Since you allocate in small chunks I suspect this is where  the difference comes from.

Comment: You could allocate multiple "chunks" at once, so that some of your pointers are within one of the allocated chunks.  Makes keeping track of things when you need to deallocate things trickier.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. I have tried to run your program with several different `MANY` values and it always had reasonably small overhead.  Could you show some code that allows to reproduce it?

Comment: Most allocators will round up the number of bytes to a multiple of 16. 20 bytes -> 32 bytes, 33 bytes -> 48 bytes, 48 bytes -> 48 bytes. How to deal with it? By taking a deep breath and stopping to worry about it.

Comment: _I do not think I will do better job than gnu or facebook people_ I am not sure, you could, but if you think you can't, may be you're right. It actually depends on why? would you want to do this. And it's not a matter of doing a better job, it's about doing the right job, the one that fits your needs.

Comment: @ILoveCoding what system you are using? I am using Arch Linux on 32 bit ARM, but tried it on Arch Linux on 64 bit XEON and got ~62 MB usage

Comment: @Nick should you include the "ARM" tag?

Comment: No, same thing happen regardless of the architecture Arm, x86 or x86_64. I am on Arm at the moment and give Arm usage.

Comment: @Nick your above comment says *"pieces are different sizes"*, so the code you posted does **not** state your problem. Also, I see you have used `long int` type to work with `1000000` so is that a 16-bit processor, perhaps with bank switching?

Comment: @Nick said *"tried it on Arch Linux on 64 bit XEON and got ~62 MB usage"*. You allocate memory for 1000000 records of 43-->64 bytes each, which will use 64000000 bytes, or ~62Mb. What are you on?

Comment: @Weather Vane you are probably correct for "different sizes". about the Arm is 32 bit, no particular reason for long int, i am developing it on normal 64 bit intel but from time to time checking it on Arm for compatibility.

Comment: @Nick your comment to an answer said "I believe memory is wasted, because I have a file with around 500 MB data. I can not load it on machine with 6 GB free RAM (Intel i5)." That's not ARM now is it? Your posts are getting contradictory.

Comment: @Weather Vane I don't have the test data with me. I will check this tomorrow and will update the question with exact breakdown with sizes and so on

Comment: @Weather Vane as I said I test my code on 4-5 systems, but mostly on i5 / 10 GB ram and ARM v7 / 2 GB ram. Heavy "memory" things I do on i5. Will post exact memory usage tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69342/discussion-between-nick-and-weather-vane).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, overhead. There is a small overhead in the `malloc` structure. I think it's about 8 bytes per `malloc`. Also (partly for alignment, partly for practicality, and partly to minimise the effect below), memory allocations are going to be rounded up in size to a multiple of a small power of 2.

Secondly, fragmentation. Suppose you allocate 3 900 byte blocks, A, B, and C, and the allocator chooses to allocate them sequentially. Next, suppose B is freed. As the hole is smaller than the OS page size, the 'hole' that B is in can't be given back to the OS. If all subsequent allocations using `malloc` are larger than 900 bytes, the hole will never be filled - i.e. its wasted. If (say) a 600 byte allocation comes along, it *might* be placed in the hole, but that's then going to leave a 300 byte hole. No allocator is going to perform perfectly in this situation.

Comment: there are no de-allocations in the code, just malloc()'s I will do profiling of the data tomorrow and will post the result here.

Comment: You're quite sure `printf` and `stdio` buffering never allocate (or free) any memory internally?

Comment: not sure for printf(), but fopen() for sure do. however "hole" should be small comparing to the rest of the usage.

Comment: `printf()` is only in the loop when `malloc()` fails.

Comment: I did following file https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM2/blob/master/malloc_tools.h and run the test with it. Seems all additional space is the overhead. I also profiled the "pieces" of data by size and I found I have lots of "non so aligned" pieces, for example 17 bytes long - on x86_64 this gets "rounded" to 32 bytes and on Arm it is rounded to 24 byte. Finally I tried Doug Lea malloc and it give me surprisingly good results. Seems like I will need to find or made custom allocator after all :)

Answer (score 0):

On a modern OS, a common implementation of `malloc` will request large chunks of virtual memory space and split it up into allocation pools.  It will then hand out that memory from these pools as due to its own optimization parameters (whether by size, thread, fragment reduction, etc.).  A naive view of memory sees this as wasted.  However, virtual memory is not necessarily backed by physical pages until it is put to use, when the OS will backfill a mapping for it on demand (similar to how paging works, but with anonymous memory-backing).  Therefore, the number that you view as being used by your process is not necessarily real memory that is being consumed, simply allocated VM space waiting to be used.

Comment: I believe memory is wasted, because I have a file with around 500 MB data. I can not load it on machine with 6 GB free RAM (Intel i5).

Comment: @Nick But you mentioned ARM. Be clear, which platform, what problem.